# Formatted output with left-justified formatting python

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples `myTuple = (string1,integer,string2,string3)` that I want to print to a file, with only the second string left justified.

I can form the following string:

```
myString = '%4s  %5i  %3s %3s\n' % myTuple
```

which I then print to a file

```
f.write(myString)
```

`string2` can be 1,2, or 3 characters long. So for various combinations I get the following format:

```
XXXX      1    X XXX
XXXX      2   XX XXX
XXXX      3  XXX XXX
```

What I want to have instead is

```
XXXX      1  X   XXX
XXXX      2  XX  XXX
XXXX      3  XXX XXX
```

Is it possible to left-justify the second string?

Comment: look into the `.format()` function

Comment: @PeterWood I saw that question, but couldn't figure out how to combine strings and floats/integers.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate change your first `%3s` to `%-3s`...